# Assuming a root and simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I want to simplify an expression assuming a given value is a root. Say s[v] is a root of f[x,u]-f[x,v]. Sometimes *Assuming* works, for example,

```
f[x_, y_] := (1 - y x);
Assuming[f[s[v], u] == f[s[v], v],
        Simplify[f[s[v], u] - f[s[v], v]]
```

works as desired, yielding 0.

Sometimes it fails:

```
f[x_, y_] := (1 - Exp[-y x] - y x);
Assuming[f[s[v], u] == f[s[v], v], 
         Simplify[f[s[v], u] - f[s[v], v]]]
```

Even

```
f[x_, y_] := (1 - Exp[-y x] - y x);
Assuming[Simplify[f[s[v], u] - f[s[v], v]] == 0, 
         Simplify[Simplify[f[s[v], u] - f[s[v], v]]]]
```

appears to ignore or not recognize the assumption. Is there some way to overcome this short of Holding and Releasing f[s[v],u] and f[s[v],v] judiciously?

Comment: `f[x_, y_] := (1 - Exp[-y x] - y x); 

Simplify[f[s[v], u] - f[s[v], v] /. 
   Solve[f[s[v], u] == f[s[v], v], u][[1]]] // Quiet`

Comment: Thanks for thinking about this. Your workaround certainly handles the example provided. But I simplified the original problem from a case in which "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve." Hence my desire to exploit Assuming, i.e. to simply asset that s[v] is a root.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_, y_] := (1 - Exp[-y x] - y x);
```

Use [`TagSet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSet.html) or [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html)

If the variables `u` and `v` **are not** literal

```
ClearAll[f]

f /: (f[s[v_], u_] /; u =!= v) = f[s[v], v];

f[s[v], u] - f[s[v], v]

(* 0 *)

f[s[x], y] - f[s[x], x]

(* 0 *)
```

If the variables `u` and `v` **are** literal

```
ClearAll[f]

f /: f[s[v], u] = f[s[v], v];

f[s[v], u] - f[s[v], v]

(* 0 *)

f[s[x], y] - f[s[x], x]

(* -f[s[x], x] + f[s[x], y] *)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. I was not familiar with TagSet. This language is so rich. There's always another nugget to uncover.

Answer (score 0):

Still struggling with this and have come across what appears to be a better answer. It was suggested by TransformationFunctions, which that proved a bit disappointing, but led to this approach. Illustrated with the example:

```
f[x_, y_] := (1 - Exp[-y x] - y x);
Assuming[f[s[v], u] == f[s[v], v], 
         Simplify[f[s[v], u] - f[s[v], v]]]
```

The assertion that f[s[v], u] == f[s[v], v] is equivalent to: Exp[-u s[v]] = Exp[-v s[v]] - u s[v] + v s[v]

So define a tranformation rule:

```
svIsARoot = #/.Exp[-u s[v]] -> Exp[-v s[v]] - u s[v] + v s[v]&;
```

Appending that to Simplify's rules sometimes works -- as in

```
ClearAll[f, svIsARoot];
f[x_, y_] := (1 - Exp[-y x] - y x);  
svIsARoot = #/.Exp[-u s[v]] -> Exp[-v s[v]] - u s[v] + v s[v]&; 
Simplify[f[s[v],v]-f[s[v],u],  TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, svIsARoot}]
```

But for more complex expressions, I found

```
ClearAll[f, svIsARoot];
f[x_, y_] := (1 - Exp[-y x] - y x);  
svIsARoot = #/.Exp[-u s[v]] -> Exp[-v s[v]] - u s[v] + v s[v]&; 
Simplify[svIsARoot@(f[s[v],v]-f[s[v],u])]
```

more reliable.